# Hacer casting de un tipo desconocido y meterlo en una columna del datarow

Tags: c#, datatable

Tengo un DataTable que ha sido creado con las mismas columnas que otro DataTable.

```
DataTable dtAux = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
      dtAux.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[i].ToString(), dt.Columns[i].GetType());
}
```

Posteriormente quiero ir añadiendo registros al dataTable dtAux, en función de que cumplan determinados requisitos

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvAux.Rows.Count; i++)
{
      foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
      {
          if ((dr[0].ToString() == dgvAux.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
          {
               DataRow drAux = dtAux.NewRow();
               drAux[0] =  ((drAux[0].GetType()) (dr[0].ToString()));
               ...
               ...
               ...  
               dtAux.Rows.Add(drAux);
          }
       }
}
```

El problema me surge cuando intento meter en `dr[0]` el valor, previamente casteado, no consigo que lo haga bien

Comment: a que te refieres con "no consigo que lo haga bien" ?  te da erorres, problemas?

Comment: Tu primera parte de código no es necesaria. Puedes simplemente hacer `DataTable dtAux = dt.Clone();`. Y no entiendo tu segundo codigo...no te valdría `DataTable dtAux = dt.Copy();`?

Comment: @lois6b Hola, es la parte drAux[0] =  ((drAux[0].GetType()) (dr[0].ToString())); la que no me hace bien porque no son del mismo tipo y no consigo castear esto bien

Comment: Intenta algo como `drAux[0] = Convert.ChangeType(dr[0], drAux[0].GetType());` . Aunque sigo sin tener ni idea de lo que intentas... :)

Comment: @Pikoh la parte DataTable dtAux = dt.Clone() me viene perfecto, gracias, no lo conocia, sin embargo no me vale con hacer un copy de toda la tabla porque solo tengo que copiar las filas que cumplan los requisitos. gracias

Comment: Aun asi, no entiendo por que tienes que castear nada. Las columnas de dtAux son identicas a las de dt. Si lo que quieres es copiar una fila si se cumple una condición, comprueba la condicion y haz algo como `drAux.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;`

Comment: @Pikoh jejeje, si, lo que intento realmente es de un datagridview crear un datatable con todos los registros que cumplen determinados requisitos en ese datagridview

Comment: @Nuevamente gracias, no conocia la propiedad item array, asi que simplemente con: if ((dr[0].ToString() == dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()))
                                {
                                    DataRow drAux = dtAux.NewRow();
                                    drAux.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
                                    dtAux.Rows.Add(drAux);
                                } funciona, si lo pones como respuesta te la doy por buena, muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para copiar un `DataRow` a otro, siempre y cuando ambos tengan la misma estructura, puedes copiar simplemente la propiedad `ItemArray` de uno a otro, asi que tu código quedaría asi:

```
if ((dr[0].ToString() == dt.Rows[0][0].ToString())) 
{ 
     DataRow drAux = dtAux.NewRow(); 
     drAux.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray; 
     dtAux.Rows.Add(drAux); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin dar muchas explicaciones es complicado pero,

```
drAux[0] =  ((drAux[0].GetType()) (dr[0].ToString()));
```

Veo que intentas castear `dr[0].ToString()` al tipo de `drAux[o]`, pero al hacer `ToString()` el tipo siempre va a ser cadena.

Por tanto te va a dar fallo si el tipo de `drAux[0]` no es string también.

Comment: hola, realmente la solucion es como indica @pikoh, usando la propiedad ItemArray que desconocia. gracias.